# Restart a Moviclip from the stage after stoping it

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, movieclip

On my main stage I have a few Movieclips, which all start at a different frame position, and also end at a different frame position. So I put a keyframe to the Movieclips, after the animation is finished, and put a  `stop()` on it. After all animations are finished, the main stage also gets a `stop()` and a replay button appears. Now if I click on the replay button, every movieclip should start again - of course. I have tried `gotoAndPlay(1)` but the moviclips are not starting with that, only the mainstage (of course, i know that moviclips have their own timeline.. ) So how can I restart every animation with just the one click on the replay button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flash, movieclips are running seperate from the Main Stage.
In order to run all the movieclips, you should restart all the movieclips:
Let's say the names of the movieclips are MovieClip1, MovieClip2 and MovieClip3.

```
on(release){
    gotoAndPlay(1);
    MovieClip1.gotoAndPlay(1);
    MovieClip2.gotoAndPlay(1);
    MovieClip3.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: I have already tried that, but then I get an error: Accress of undefined property MovieClip1.

(when MovieClip1 is the name of my MovieClip)

Comment: Did you typed the name in the textbox for the <Instance Name>?